# What is the best way to presetting checkboxes in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have template with checkbox

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <input type="checkbox" id="isDeletedCheckbox" {{action "toggleIsDeleted" "isDeletedCheckbox" on="change"}}/>
</div>
```

And I have Route with

```
afterModel(model) {
    this.controllerFor(this.get('routeName')).set('model', model)
},
```

I tried to use

```
setupController() {
    if (this.controller.get('model').get('isDeleted')) {
        this.controller.set("isDeletedCheckbox", true);
    }
}
```

or

```
setupController() {     
   if (this.controller.get('model').get('isDeleted')) {
        $("#isDeletedCheckbox").checked(true);
   }
}
```

but it does not help to preset the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `{{input type="checkbox"}}` [helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_checkbox).

```
{{input type="checkbox" name="isEmberized" checked=model.isDeleted}}
```

If your model looks like this:

```
model() {
  return { isDeleted: true };
}
```

---

What you should *never* no is something like

```
$("#isDeletedCheckbox").checked(true);
```

in a route or controller. *Only* use direct DOM manipulation in a component!

Comment: Because at that point your DOM is maybe not present yet. The `didInsertElement` hook on the `component` is called when the DOM is ready.